# Do I need to add single quote to parameters sent from JDBC to SQL Server 2019 database to avoid implicit conversion?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

This are the parameters in the program

```
st.setString(2, field_ex_2);
st.setString(3, field_ex_3);
st.setString(4, field_ex_4)
```

And this is the way SQL Server received them:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_ISSUE WHERE branch=347 AND pos = 3 AND "SEQUENCE" = 473
```

The fields are defined as varchar and this select generates an implicit conversion which made the processor rises to 30 % or more.

We solved similar cases changing application and table when possible.

We see that problem is solved just adding single quote to value:

```
WHERE branch='347' AND pos = '3' AND "SEQUENCE" = '473'
```

We need to understand why JDBC send parameters as numeric or at least they arrived without single quotes when defined as string.

Comment: The question is unclear. The queries contain hard-coded values, not parameters. In a parameterized query, the parameter values are passed outside the query itself, as actual, real parameters. The database compiles the parameterized query into a parameterized execution plan and executes that plan using the parameter values. The parameters are never inserted in the query or plan. The server caches execution plans based on the query text and can reuse the same plan with different parameters instead of recompiling it\

Comment: The only way the raw values would appear inside the query is if the application constructed a query string itself from input. That's bad.  Imagine what would happen if one field contained `1; DROP TABLE USERS; --`. It's unsafe and prone to SQL injection attacks, formatting problems (which is probably what's wrong here) and forces the server to recompile the same query every time, even if it could reused.

Comment: Please show your actual Java code, the JDBC driver you use, and how you determine that this is the query string that was sent. As far as I'm aware, the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver does not inline parameters and prepares statements separately from sending the parameter values for execution.

Comment: How did you determine what SQL Server actually received? Did you find that in SQL Profiler or Extended Events? Or is this some (broken) application-level logging on the Java side of the fence? A correctly performing JDBC prepared statement does not embed the parameter values inside the statement at all, they are transmitted to the server as accompanying data structures.